# Fix Vagrant up after Windows 10 anniversary update

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, windows-update, vagrant

I faced this problem at this morning, while I was trying to start developing (working), but vagrant up did not agree with me.

The virtual machine (I use Scotch-box -box) simply did not start. Also the Virtual Box -application did not start at all. Not even for a blink or to show a error message.

How to fix this?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Background:** Windows 10 is now 1 year old and released so called anniversary update last week. Among many updates, it also broke up things like forced cs:go fps to 30(?) and ofc - virtual box and vagrant too.

I've read that someone had these problems too, but fixed it by disabling [Hyper-V](http://www.windows10update.com/2015/04/how-to-turn-on-or-enable-hyper-v-in-windows-10/). This however was not my case, since I didn't have the thing even enabled.

**Solution:**

1. Update vagrant if you don't have the latest version installed.
2. Update Oracle Virtual Box
3. Restart your machine
4. Vagrant up
5. Boom - done.

**Why:** For some reason, the previous Virtual Box version vas not compatible with the new Windows 10 update. Even with different compatibility modes. It didn't even show errors when I tried to launch it. I first tried to only update it without updating Vagrant, but then when I tried to run vagrant up again, it forced me to downgrade the Virtual Box, so I was back to square one, eh?

Luckily this time the process to get things back on, was relatively simply.

Hope someone finds this helpfull!

Comment: Thanks, I too had to uninstall virtualbox and then install the latest version of Vagrant.